# How is separability and local compactness used in the following lemma that $X_n \to X$, $X_n$ measurble, implies $X$ is measurable?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Conseder the following Lemma from a book by K.L. Chung. It is stated just before it that we assume the "range space" (or state space since $X_n $ is a stochastic process) is a separable, locally compact metric space. I cannot see where this fact is used in the proof. Please help me with elucidating it!

Here **T** denotes $[0, \infty) $ and $\Omega $ is some arbitrary probability space.

[image: Picture of Lemma]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I can see separability and local compactness are not used in this proof. Perhaps Chung uses those at a later stage.

Comment: Okey thanks! I must have missunderstood his statement then. Maybe as you say this assumption is needed later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separable plus locally compact implies metrizable, which is crucial to the proof, via the representation of the open set  $G$ as an $\mathcal F_\sigma$ set. Separable metric would also suffice.

Comment: Separable plus locally compact does not imply metrizable.  $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{R}$ is a counterexample.  *Second countable* plus locally compact does imply metrizable. However, the text actually assumes that the range space is metric.

Comment: Indeed, I misspoke.  (Spend too much time in metric spaces...)